# Asp Net Core : How Can I Copy *.json Config/Content File of Dependent Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to Asp Net Core.

I have two projects:

1. Project A is an AspNetCore web api. It has an appsettings.json file that is included in the publishOptions.
2. Project B depends on A. I added A to project B as a dependency. But when I run the "dotnet publish B", the A::appsettings.json is not copied. Can anyone advice?

I have tried adding A::appsettings to A::project.json's "buildOptions.copyToOutput/embed/compile.include", but it seems they did not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mappings` property in the `buildOptions`/`publishOptions` section in your `project.json` file.

In **src/B/project.json**:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": {
    "mappings": {
      "appsettings.json": {
        "includeFiles": "../A/appsettings.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should do the same in the `buildOptions` section to also preserve the file during a `dotnet build`.  This example is just copying a single file, but you can also use paths to copy multiple files:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "dest/path": "./src/path"
    }
}
```

---

Source: [The project.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#buildoptions).